# How to mask all URLs for static site hosted on S3?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a static site, consisting of 3 pages (home, about and contact).
This was a wordpress site exported as html and uploaded to s3.
When i access the site home page url shows domain name correctly but after clicking on about link, it shows s3 path in the address bar instead of domain name.
eg. 
expected output : example.com/about
current output : s3-region.amazon.com/example.com/about/index.html

I am using Route53 and Cloudfront along with S3.

Comment: Is the generated content from WordPress using absolute paths or relative in its page links? Are you able to post the URL so I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

the paths were absolute paths for the s3 objects.
Modified the href tag to relative paths(relative to index.html) and it worked.

Note: The cloudfront caches the content so you may not see the changes even after clearing the browser cache. 
Hence, to see the changes, use s3 url for index.html and then click on the links (about, contact us, etc)

Comment: You can also send CloudFront an [invalidation request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) using the path `*` to clear all the objects from all the CloudFront caches.  The first 1,000 such requests per month are free, but after that there is a fee. The operation will complete in a few minutes. The status of the invalidation is visible in the console.